# Workbench table import

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The problem is, that I have two separate projects, which need to be merged. Merged in the sense that I need to get all of the tables from project 2 to project 1. After quite a bit of google-ing I only found info about ways how to import an SQL file or a whole db. Is there a way to simply copy/import tables into an existing project? One by one import is fine also.

All help and info is appreciated.

EDIT:

As soon as I posted this, I found the answer:
[How to copy table between two models in Mysql workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119500/how-to-copy-table-between-two-models-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: simply export db from project 1 and import it in project-2