# MySQL Workbench: Deleting multiple tables from Physical Schemas

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a smart way that deleting multiple tables from `Physical Schemas` view.

I know right-clicking a table and hitting `Delete ...` does the job, But it doesn't work well for thousands of tables. Selecting multiple tables and use right-clicking and hit `Delete ...` doesn't work as I expected. It deletes only one table.

How can I do that? I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an oversight or design error. You can only delete one table at a time. In order to have a better functionality implemented file a feature request on http://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I actually want to do is copying some tables from a model to another model through the way which explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17121803/3591946 . To do this, I need to delete all of tables except new ones so that I can merge two models that have conflict in our Git repository through the way.